# Parsing text in BASH

Tags: bash

I have a username system.  The user picks a username, password and pin number and this is saved into UPP.db.  I want to be able to parse this text so that a user can either be edited (Change password) or Deleted (Remove Line).  I have coded a solution for both but both return me with an error and jump to the "Else" part of my If statement.  I will provide the code for the edit section as the delete is pretty similar and would be redundant providing both.

```
echo "Please enter the username you wish to edit"
read usernamecheck

usernamesearch=$( grep $usernamecheck\$ UPP.db | cut -d" " -f1 )

if [ $usernamecheck = $usernamesearch ]
        then
        echo "Please enter $usernamesearch PIN"
                read pincheck
                pinupdate=$( grep $pincheck\$ UPP.db | cut -d" " -f3 )
                if [[ $pin = $pinupdate && $usernamecheck = $usernamesearch ]]
                then
                    echo "The user `grep "$pin"\$ UPP.db | cut -d" " -f1`'s password is about to be changed "
                    echo "Please enter the new password"
                    read newpass
                    passwordcheck=$( grep $pincheck\$ UPP.db | cut -d" " -f2 )
                    sed -i "s/$passwordcheck/$newpass/g" UPP.db
                    echo "Password changed"
                else
                    echo "The PIN is incorrect"
                fi
        else
                echo "This username is not reconised"
fi
;;
```

Comment: What are the fields of your data file? I'm thinking grep is really the wrong tool here.

Comment: Quote ALL variables in `[ ... ]` e.g. (`if [ "$usernamecheck" = "$usernamesearch" ]`) ... and as a general rule everywhere else *except* inside `[[ ... ]]` Also `if [[ $pin = $pinupdate && $usernamecheck = $usernamesearch ]]` should be `if [[ $pin = $pinupdate ]] && [[ $usernamecheck = $usernamesearch ]]`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You can use && inside `[[...]]`, just not inside `[...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

string equality comparisons will be more precise than regular expressions. Here, I use `awk` not `grep` to enable that. You might want to keep the bash man page handy while you read this.

```
read -p "Please enter the username you wish to edit: " usernamecheck

# extract all the fields at once
read -r db_user db_pass db_pin < <(
    awk -v name="$usernamecheck" '$1 == name {print; exit}' UPP.db
)

if [[ -z $db_user ]]; then
    echo "This username is not reconised"
else
    read -p "Please enter $db_user PIN: " pincheck
    if [[ "$db_pin" != "$pincheck" ]]; then
        echo "The PIN is incorrect"
    else
        echo "Changing password for user $db_user:"
        while true; do 
            read -s -p "Please enter the new password: " newpass
            echo
            read -s -p "Please re-enter the new password: " newpass2
            echo
            if [[ "$newpass" == "$newpass2" ]]; then
                break
            fi
            echo "Passwords do not match. Try again."
        done

        ln UPP.db "UPP.db.$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")"    # create a backup copy
        temp=$(mktemp)

        # update the password
        awk -v newpw="$newpass" -v name="$db_user" '
            $1 == name {$2 = newpw}
            {print}
        ' UPP.db > "$temp" && mv "$temp" UPP.db

        echo "Password changed"
    fi
fi
```

Style tip: in an if-else-end construct, put the smaller block first, then the else-block is close to the condition. Aids readability.

If this plain text file, containing user passwords, is anywhere close to the internet, you're f*cked.

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you very much.  This is not going anywhere near the internet so no worries there, thanks again.

Comment: Quick Follow up Question, You have used `If [[ -z $db_user ]]; then
    echo "This username is not reconised"
else` to check if a username does not exist on the list.  Is there an opposite function to -z that can check if a username DOES exist from the same file?

Comment: Sure: `[[ -n $db_user ]]` will succeed if the variable is not empty.